# tic tac toe vhdl student project

Tags: vhdl

The problem is that the outputs are not matching with the ifs .I want, example line A if everything is 1 the output should be 11. but it is not to be

```
library ieee;  
 use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;  
 use ieee.numeric_std.all;  

 entity galo_ports is  
  port( LinA : in unsigned(2 downto 0); 
    LinB : in unsigned(2 downto 0);
    LinC : in unsigned(2 downto 0);

    output : out unsigned(1 downto 0)); 
 end galo_ports;

ARCHITECTURE main OF galo_ports IS
SIGNAL values: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
SIGNAL condition1A: boolean;
SIGNAL condition2A: boolean;
SIGNAL condition3A: boolean;
SIGNAL condition1B: boolean;
SIGNAL condition2B: boolean;
SIGNAL condition3B: boolean;
SIGNAL condition1C: boolean;
SIGNAL condition2C: boolean;
SIGNAL condition3C: boolean;
SIGNAL condition1COL1: boolean;
SIGNAL condition2COL1: boolean;
SIGNAL condition3COL1: boolean;
SIGNAL condition1COL2: boolean;
SIGNAL condition2COL2: boolean;
SIGNAL condition3COL2: boolean;
SIGNAL condition1COL3: boolean;
SIGNAL condition2COL3: boolean;
SIGNAL condition3COL3: boolean;
SIGNAL condition1DIG1: boolean;
SIGNAL condition2DIG1: boolean;
SIGNAL condition3DIG1: boolean;
SIGNAL condition1DIG2: boolean;
SIGNAL condition2DIG2: boolean;
SIGNAL condition3DIG2: boolean;
BEGIN
values <= "10";

--CONDIÇÃOES:
--LINHA 1
condition1A <= LinA(0) = LinA(1) and LinA(1) = LinA(2);
condition2A <= LinA(0) = values(0) or LinA(0) = values(1);
condition3A <= LinA(0) = values(1);
--LINHA 2
condition1B <= LinB(0) = LinB(1) and LinB(1) = LinB(2);
condition2B <= LinB(0) = values(0) or LinB(0) = values(1);
condition3B <= LinB(0) = values(1);
--LINHA 3
condition1C <= LinC(0) = LinC(1) and LinC(1) = LinC(2);
condition2C <= LinC(0) = values(0) or LinC(0) = values(1);
condition3C <= LinC(0) = values(1);
--COLUNA 1
condition1COL1 <= LinA(0) = LinB(0) and LinB(0) = LinC(0);
condition2COL1 <= LinA(0) = values(0) or LinA(0) = values(1);
condition3COL1 <= LinA(0) = values(1);
--COLUNA 2
condition1COL2 <= LinA(1) = LinB(1) and LinB(1) = LinC(1);
condition2COL2 <= LinA(1) = values(0) or LinA(1) = values(1);
condition3COL2 <= LinA(1) = values(1);
--COLUNA 3
condition1COL3 <= LinA(2) = LinB(2) and LinB(2) = LinC(2);
condition2COL3 <= LinB(2) = values(0) or LinA(2) = values(1);
condition3COL3 <= LinB(2) = values(1);
--DIAGONAL 1
condition1DIG1 <= LinA(0) = LinB(1) and LinB(1) = LinC(2);
condition2DIG1 <= LinA(0) = values(0) or LinA(0) = values(1);
condition3DIG1 <= LinA(0) = values(1);
--DIAGONAL 2
condition1DIG2 <= LinA(2) = LinB(1) and LinB(1) = LinC(0);
condition2DIG2 <= LinA(2) = values(0) or LinA(2) = values(1);
condition3DIG2 <= LinA(2) = values(1);
    PROCESS(LinA, LinB, LinC)
    BEGIN
        --LINHA 1
        IF condition1A=TRUE and condition2A=TRUE and condition3A=TRUE THEN output <= "11";
        END IF;
        --LINHA 2
        IF (condition1B) and (condition2B) and (condition3B) THEN output <= "11"; ELSE output <="00";
        END IF;
        --LINHA 3
        IF condition1C and condition2C and condition3C THEN output <= "11";
        END IF;
        --COLUNA 1
        IF condition1COL1 and condition2COL1 and condition3COL1 THEN output <= "11";
        END IF;
        --COLUNA 2
        IF condition1COL2 and condition2COL2 and condition3COL2 THEN output <= "11";
        END IF;
        --COLUNA 3
        IF condition1COL3 and condition2COL3 and condition3COL3 THEN output <= "11";
        END IF;
        --DIAGONAL 1
        IF condition1DIG1 and condition2DIG1 and condition3DIG1 THEN output <= "11";
        END IF;
        --DIAGONAL 2
        IF condition1DIG2 and condition2DIG2 and condition3DIG2 THEN output <= "11";
        END IF;

    END PROCESS;
END main;
```

The game contains a board of 9 positions, each player makes his move in a house that is free by marking it with an "0" (player A) or "1" (Player B).

Victory is awarded to the player who can put 3 "0" or 3 "1" horizontally, vertically or diagonally.

The solution should signal at the exit which player wins or signal the draw - if no player can achieve the defined goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed my original answer since @pm101 noted that it was completely out of track.

After compiling your design, the warnings state the obvious reason:

> VHDL Process Statement warning at galo_ports.vhd(142): signal
>   "condition1A" is read inside the Process Statement but isn't in the
>   Process Statement's sensitivity list

The values of `conditionXXX` signals are updated when `linA`, `linB` or `linC` changes. However, the process is executed at the same time and those condition signals' values are not yet updated. If you are simulating the design, you would see that the value of `output` lags: it is updated when the inputs change, but it would probably show the result of the game with the previous inputs.

Fix the process sensitivity list to contain all the condition signals. Then the process will be executed when your `conditionXXX` signals change and the conditional expressions are evaluated correctly. So something like:

```
PROCESS(condition1A, condition2A, condition3A, condition1B, condition2B, condition3B, condition1C, condition2C, condition3C, condition1COl1, condition2COL1, condition3COL1, condition1COL2, condition2COL2, condition3COL2, condition1COL3, condition2COL3, condition3COL3, condition1DIG1, condition2DIG1, condition3DIG1, condition1DIG2, condition2DIG2, condition3DIG2)
```

Furthermore, I would wrap that list of conditions into one `IF` block with `ELSIF` statements. Then in the `ELSE` statement you have to also define what the value of the `output` is when there is not a winner (or 0 is the winner):

```
  --LINHA 1
  IF condition1A=TRUE and condition2A=TRUE and condition3A=TRUE THEN output <= "11";
  --LINHA 2
  ELSIF (condition1B) and (condition2B) and (condition3B) THEN output <= "11";
  --LINHA 3
  ELSIF condition1C and condition2C and condition3C THEN output <= "11";
  --COLUNA 1
  ELSIF condition1COL1 and condition2COL1 and condition3COL1 THEN output <= "11";
  --COLUNA 2
  ELSIF condition1COL2 and condition2COL2 and condition3COL2 THEN output <= "11";
  --COLUNA 3
  ELSIF condition1COL3 and condition2COL3 and condition3COL3 THEN output <= "11";
  --DIAGONAL 1
  ELSIF condition1DIG1 and condition2DIG1 and condition3DIG1 THEN output <= "11";
  --DIAGONAL 2
  ELSIF condition1DIG2 and condition2DIG2 and condition3DIG2 THEN output <= "11";
  ELSE output <= "00"; -- 0 wins or no winner. 
  END IF;
```